# SqLite for Uno on Native platforms - How to do it?

Tags: sqlite, uno-platform

I'm just starting with Uno. I'm an experienced UWP developer and have done some Mac development (With Xamarin Native).

I've created an Uno solution, and have removed the WASM, WPF and Mobile target projects (only interested in UWP and MacOS)

Now I want to use SQLite in my Uno solution, and not sure how that's achieved. I cant add nuget packages to the shared project, so Im guessing that I need to create an interface class to declare the data access requirements, and then implement that interface separately in the UWP and MacOS projects.

Is this how it's done, or have I got this wrong ?

Does anyone know where on the Uno docs I can find out how to do this

Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use the Salute.net project, it has cross platform specific SQL binaries for each platform that you can used with a shared access layer. It's one of the simplest ways to use Sqlite with full object mapping and basic LINQ support

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was mostly right. After reading the docs again it seems that rather than interfaces, you need to use partial classes to implement the required class across the platforms you need.

I found out how to do it here:

https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html